# On maximal submodules of projective modules

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra

I know that any non-zero projective module has a maximal submodule. But is it true that any proper submodule is contained in a maximal submodule !?

Comment: What types of rings are you considering? Commutative, with 1, Noetherian?

Comment: @user115654 Rings with identity but not necessary commutative.

Comment: In the literature, I have seen modules satisfying "every proper submodule is contained in a maximal submodule" called, **Bass modules**.  Faith also called them "B-objects" at one point, which (I hope) didn't stick.  I ran across this researching for a [blog post](https://databaseofringtheory.wordpress.com/2023/11/02/semi-artinian-and-semi-noetherian-modules/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and consider $M=\mathbb{Q}$. There is a projective module $F$ and surjective homomorphism $f:F\to M$ (for example, take $F=R^{(M)}$ and $f(e_m) = m$). The submodule $\ker(f) \leq F$ is not contained in any maximal submodule, since the lattice of submodules containing $\ker(f)$ is isomorphic to the submodule lattice of $M$, and the submodule lattice of $M$ contains no (proper) maximal elements.

Thanks for the nice question. I was surprised by the answer.

---

A related question: Well which rings work?

**Proposition:** The following are equivalent:

- Every proper submodule of a projective module is contained in a maximal submodule
- Every proper submodule of a module is contained in a maximal submodule
- Every module has a maximal submodule

*Proof:* The second clearly implies both of the others. Let $K < M$. Then there is a free module $F$ and surjective homomorphism $f:F \to M$. Let $L=f^{-1}(K)$. In the first case, we can find some maximal submodule $X$ with $L \leq X \lessdot F$. Then $K \leq f(X) \lessdot M$, and so the first case implies the second. In the third case, the module $M/K$ contains a maximal submodule $L/K \lessdot M/K$. Then $K \leq L \lessdot M$, so the third case implies the second. $\square$

In the commutative case, Hamsher studied these rings, first (1966) in the noetherian case, and then (1967) in the general case. I'm reading through these now, and might read the noncomm results too. Let me know if you are interested.

- Hamsher, Ross M.
  “Commutative, noetherian rings over which every module has a maximal submodule.”
  Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 17 (1966) 1471–1472.
  MR[200303](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=200303)
  DOI:[10.2307/2035767](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2035767)
- Hamsher, Ross M.
  “Commutative rings over which every module has a maximal submodule.”
  Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 18 (1967) 1133–1137.
  MR[217059](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=217059)
  DOI:[10.2307/2035815](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2035815)

Comment: Noncomm (beside Hamsher (1967)) are Faith (1995) http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1336364 and Koifman (1970) http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=262303; Renault (1970) http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=214623 improves on Hamsher (1970) a bit and gives a counterexample to Bass's conjecture.